# TCP/IP connection with scapy

Tags: python, linux, networking, tcp, scapy

I'm trying to implement a little netcat-like utility using `scapy` (where i can do low-level modifications to the IP packets), but I am unable to initiate a proper connection.

I tried to create a simple test-program that connects to a remote host and sends some string over:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import sys
from scapy.all import *

dst = sys.argv[1]
sport = random.randint(1024, 65535)
dport = int(sys.argv[2])
data = 'hello\r\n'

ip = IP(dst=dst, frag=0)
SYN = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='S', seq=1000)
SYNACK = sr1(ip/SYN)
ACK = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
INITACK = sr1(ip/ACK)
PUSHACK = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='PA', seq=INITACK.ack, ack=INITACK.seq + 1)
RESPONSE = sr1(ip/PUSHACK/Raw(load=data))
```

On the receiving side i have a `nc -l -p 6666` running.

When I invoke the script, i get the following output on the sender:

```sh
$ sudo ./test.py REMOTE 6666
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.......*
Received 8 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
*
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
*
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

But the receiving netcat never outputs any data (I did check whether I can send data to the remote with `echo foo | nc REMOTE 6666`, and it does work nicely).

When running a `tcpdump` on the receiver, I can see the following output:

```
23:31:58.205257 IP SENDER.4902 > RECEIVER.6666: Flags [S], seq 1000, win 8192, options [mss 536], length 0
23:31:58.205279 IP RECEIVER.6666 > SENDER.4902: Flags [S.], seq 1928493439, ack 1001, win 29200, options [mss 1460], length 0
23:31:58.344181 IP SENDER.4902 > RECEIVER.6666: Flags [R], seq 1001, win 0, length 0
23:31:58.396581 IP SENDER.4902 > RECEIVER.6666: Flags [.], ack 1, win 8192, length 0
23:31:58.396593 IP RECEIVER.6666 > SENDER.4902: Flags [R], seq 1928493440, win 0, length 0
23:31:58.459286 IP SENDER.4902 > RECEIVER.6666: Flags [P.], seq 4294966296:4294966303, ack 2, win 8192, length 7
23:31:58.459296 IP RECEIVER.6666 > SENDER.4902: Flags [R], seq 1928493441, win 0, length 0
```

So: what am I doing wrong`

Comment: Sender send SYN, receiver sends back SYN,ACK. Then "sender" sends a RST.  This is from the native TCP stack that doesn't know about the connection you are trying to establish.  You will need to prevent the native TCP stack from seeing this traffic, e.g., with iptables.

Comment: interesting. fom [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144729/iptables-rule-no-actions-on-scapy-packets#comment233979_144729) i gathered that the raw-sockets used by scapy would somehow bypass `iptables`. If you can come up with an `iptables` rule that that bypasses the native TCP/IP-stack i would accept the answer ;-)

Comment: What you want to block is the packets from the reciever at the sender so that the native TCP stack does not see the SYN,ACK reply and send a reset.  You are not trying to block scapy/its raw socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel is closing the connection when it receives a SYN/ACK from your TCP partner.
if you are under linux, you can use IP table to inform the kernel that you do not wish that behaviour. Beware of the security concern if you do that.

the iptable command is the folowing:

```sh
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
iptables -L
```

your code also needs a small change.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import sys
from scapy.all import *

dst = sys.argv[1]
sport = random.randint(1024, 65535)
dport = int(sys.argv[2])
data = 'hello\r\n'

ip = IP(dst=dst, frag=0)
SYN = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='S', seq=1000)
SYNACK = sr1(ip/SYN)
ACK = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='A', seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ip/ACK)
# at this point, you and your partner are on established state.


# you can then start to send things
cur_seq=SYNACK.ack
cur_ack=SYNACK.seq + 1


PUSHACK = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags='PA', seq=cur_seq, ack=cur_ack)
cur_seq += len(data)
RESPONSE = sr1(ip/PUSHACK/Raw(load=data))
```

Comment: hmm, no dice. i no longer get the `RST` packets, but the transmission now only does `SYN`, `SYN/ACK`, and `ACK` and stalls there (according to tcpdump)

Comment: this line:INITACK = sr1(ip/ACK) means that you are expecting an answer from your partner. you should not. replace by :send(ip/ACK)

Comment: yes indeed, in the meantime i discovered that as well.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it fits

Comment: @fgagnaire could you also tell the command to revert the configuration of iptables to the original state?